# How to encode sounds on android?

Tags: android, drawable, decode, encode

Hacker can use apktool to decode from apk file to get resources of app. So how can I decode sounds, images in drawable?
Hope you can help me to prevent hacking apk.
Thanks

Comment: Hello, any one can help? please, it's very urgent problem with me

Comment: so, at the end, there is no way to protect asset folder from hacker, right? it's terrible for android!